# Progress loader in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments in an activity as follows.

[image]

I want to show progress dialog depend an fragment. I mean while open a progress dialog from `Fragment 1` I want work with `Fragment 2` without disturbing `progress dialog` of `Fragment 1`. Is it possible? If not how and where can I start to implement this feature?

Any idea will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Does it need to be a dialog? If not you could just have a progress widget on top of each fragment and show/hide as required.

Comment: @IvanWooll Thanks bro.. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
1. Fragment1 - show dialog and throw callback to activity
2. Activity get callback from Fragment1 and call method from Fragment2

[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)